# Reverting an inversion bug in Apple Mail Rules

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

Sometimes I observe a strange inversion bug in my incoming mails : the sender and title  listed in my mailbox do not correspond to the content when I open the mail.

Usually it is inverted with the mail before or after. When I open mail title A, I get content B. When I open mail titled B I get content A.

Also, mail Title A, sender A appears with prefix B in the mail list. And conversely

This happens in mailboxes I use to automatically sort incoming mails.
I have quite a long legacy rules list (~40 rules, each doing 10 to 50 tests) to handle my incoming mails, dating back decades. There must be a bug in how Apple executes the rules there.

I have little hope to fix the inversion bug, but maybe there is a way to exchange the content of inverted mails when the bug has been observed ?

PS: OS is Monterey 12.7.1, language is French, on Intel i9 8cores; this has happened for years, frequency is quite rare, maybe 1 in 1000 messages. It is not linked to the sender, mails substituted have no relation whatsoever, except for the mailbox where they are sorted to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just the mail list is wrong, it could indicate a corrupted mail index. Apple has published [instructions on how to rebuild it](https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/rebuild-mailboxes-mlhlp1227/16.0/mac/14.0).